# How to exit from recursive call in reactive form valueChanges

Tags: angular, recursion, angular-forms

I am observing `formControl`'s `valueChanges`. Form control is a `date picker`. When ever the date is selected, I am trying to reformat it to `yyyy-MM-dd` from original `MM-dd-yyyy` format. I am directly modifying the form control value. So it gives me a recursive call error. Obviously true. Is there any work around for this?

Code :

```
this.parentForm.controls['myControlName'].valueChanges.subscribe((val)=>{
this.parentForm.controls['myControlName'].setValue(this._datePipe.transform(new Date(val), 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
});

<input #inputDate type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Select date"
  [formControl]="parentForm.controls['myControlName']"
  [value]="selectedDate | date : 'MM-dd-yyyy'"/>
  <datepicker [ngModel]="selectedDate" [minDate]="minDate"
    [maxDate]="maxDate"
    [showWeeks]="false"
    [startingDay]="1"
    (selectionDone)="onSelectionDone($event)">
  </datepicker>
```

Error :

> EXCEPTION: Error in ./DatePickerComponent class
>   DatePickerComponent - inline template:13:8 caused by: too
>   much recursion error_handler.js:54 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: too much
>   recursion

Comment: What are you trying to do ?

1) Displaying date formated yyyy-MM-dd in your date picker ?

2) Converting it to  yyyy-MM-dd in your controller once it has been selected ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As form control's `setValue` method will cause a `valueChange` event by default, so you will run into a deadloop. You can set `emitEvent` to false to prevent from it.

```
this.parentForm.controls['myControlName'].setValue(this._datePipe.transform(new Date(val), 'yyyy-MM-dd'), { emitEvent: false });
```